# Ruby on Rails : No response from form submission after the page is link_to and works fine when it is directly loaded or refreshed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, link-to

I have a form which contains 3 fields (new.html.erb).  when I directly open the page it is working fine(http://localhost:3000/reviews/new).

I got another page called index.html.erb. which has a link_to "new.html.erb", when I try to movie from 'index' to 'new' and try to fill the form and submit it, there is no response.The page stays as if dead. if I try to refresh the page, it works fine.

> new.html.erb

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>


    <% provide(:title, "Review-Add")%>
    <body>

    <h1>The Movie Recommender</h1>
    <table  border="1" >
      <%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
      <tr>

        <td colspan="2"><h2>Add a Review</h2></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>


  <td>Movie Title:</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :title, size: 20  %></td>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td>Movie Stars:</td>
<td><%= f.select(:stars, options_for_select([['1 star',1],['2 stars',2],['3 stars',3],['4 stars',4],['5 stars',5]])) %></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Commentary:</td><td>
    <%= f.text_area(:commentary, size: '30x5',:value => "   Leave a comment ..." ) %>
</td></tr> 
<tr>
<td><%= f.submit "Save" %></td>
<td align="right"><%= f.submit "Cancel", type: "reset" %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><i>Rate the movie and leave a comment in the text area above</i></td></tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<hr/>
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
</body>
</html>
```

> controller :

```
def new
    @review =Review.new

  end

  def create
  @review = Review.new(params.require(:review).permit(:stars, :title, :commentary))
    if @review.save
        redirect_to review_url(@review)
    else
        redirect_to reviews_url
    end 
  end
```

This happens with all the link_to references.

can you please help me with this problem?

rake routes  :

```
     reviews GET    /reviews(.:format)             reviews#index
  new_review GET    /reviews/new(.:format)         reviews#new
            POST   /reviews(.:format)             reviews#create
     review GET    /reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#show
edit_review GET    /reviews/:id/edit(.:format)    reviews#edit
            PATCH  /reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#update
            PUT    /reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#update
            DELETE /reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#destroy
```

Is this something related to sessions ?

I uploaded all files here : [ruby code](http://www.filedropper.com/rubycode)

I am nob !!

Thanks

Comment: What javascript are you using on your forms? This sounds like a `turbolinks` issue.

Comment: i am not using any java script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, as @ptd refereed it is the problem with the form (new.html.erb) I try to debug the form.

As the tag is placed `<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>` in side the `<table>` tag  its not working. 
I moved the  form_for tag out side the `<table>` , now its working fine.

I don't know exact reason but its working fine after adjusting the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check for, and remove if you can find it `gem 'tubrolinks'` from your Gemfile. As @ptd says.

Failing this check your web browser for any errors for another clue.